# Toggle divs using class in react

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to toggle two div on the basis of a click on button , the issue is I have kept the state false in constructor

```
class  App extends Component {
constructor(props){
super(props);
this.flipScreen = this.flipScreen.bind(this);

this.state = {
   hideDashBoard: false,
   hideContractScreen:true,
 }
}
}

flipScreen(){
this.setState({hideDashBoard: true});
this.setState({hideContractScreen: false});
}
```

the html in render function

```
 <div  className={this.state.hideContractScreen ? 'hidden' : ''} style = {{position:"absolute",left:"250px",top:"50px"}}class="row"> 
<div  className={this.state.hideDashBoard ? 'hidden' : 'show'} style = {{position:"absolute",left:"250px",top:"50px"}}class="row">  
<span onClick={this.flipScreen} className="startProposal">
  Start Proposal
  </span>
```

Both the divs are present on the screen when the screen is loaded initially but on click of button the div with hidedashboard condition get classname as hidden

Comment: your html is messed up. you have className and class together?

Comment: @Apostolos Removing class worked, I was actually confused why the behavior is different on the click